# why is this animation node offset polygon rendering wrong?

Tags: animation-nodes

The scene is rendered correctly in the camera view, but wrong in the rendered image. The wrong part is an object which's using offset polygon node.
[image: lo][image]

Comment: What exactly is wrong here?

Comment: The preview rendering has the slot which is correct , the final rendering is wrong which missing the slot.

Comment: Can you show the node tree?

Comment: The 2nd screenshot included the nodes for the slot.